# Type information not showing in LINQ expression in Entity Framework 2012

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am new to Entity Framework but trying get my hands into it. After going thru many blogs I have started working on implementing it in my project but I have the following issue.

I have VS 2012 and working on a project of version 4.0.
I added `DataModel.edmx` file in my project which created 4 more files
`DataModel.Context.tt , DataModel.Designer.cs , DataModel.edmx.diagram , DataModel.tt`

Looks fine till this point. But when I try to access the table information in my Linq query. Intellisense is not showing up anything.

```
var context = new DataModelEntities();
var invoice = from c in context.Invoice select c.{//NOTHING SHOWING HERE};
```

DataModelEntities class (DataModel.Context.cs) looks like

```
namespace MySpace.Objects.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class DataModelEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DataModelEntities()
            : base("name=KKEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoice { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceContracts> InvoiceContracts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Invoice class looks like:

```
//----------- 
// <auto-generated> 
// This code was generated from a template. 
// 
// Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application. 
// Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated> 
//-------- 
namespace MySpace.Objects.DataModel 
{ 
  using System; 
  using System.Collections.Generic; 

  public partial class Invoice
  {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public int POID { get; set; }
  } 
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thank you...

Comment: Can you show us the code for the Invoice class?

Comment: Sure... It was just an POCO generated it is residing under DataModel.tt

//-----------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//--------

namespace MySpace.Objects.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;    
    public partial class Invoice
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int POID { get; set; }
    }
       
}

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` line

Comment: I observed a new theory... I have those edmx files in a C# business library and I am trying to access them thru the other web application by referring to that project. What I found is everything works fine if I access the code I posted in the Class Library but not in the Web Application... Is there any reason?

Answer (score 0):

rename

```
public DbSet<Invoice> Invoice { get; set; }
```

to

```
 public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
```

then try

```
var invoice =  c in context.Invoices.Select( c=>c.HERE)
```

Comment: No luck.. Now code looks like 
var context = new DataModelEntities();
var invoice = from c in context.Invoices select c.{//NOTHING SHOWING HERE};

Comment: var invoice = from c in context.Invoice.select(c=>c.xxx )

Comment: im not sure how query syntax handles no where clause.  Lambda version should allows .select without .where

Answer (score 0):

This is only a query specification (of type `IQueryable<Invoice>`):

```
var invoiceQuery = from c in context.Invoice select c;
```

(`invoiceQuery` is a better name than `invoice` here.) It is not the result of an executed query and no query has been sent to the database a this point. To get the result of the query you must apply an operator that causes the query to execute, for example `ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault()`, etc.:

```
var invoices = invoiceQuery.ToList();
```

This is of type `List<Invoice>`.